# When Chromedriver is started in a pipeline via a gitlab-ci.yml file, further steps do not trigger

Tags: flutter, selenium-chromedriver, gitlab-ci

After installing up Chrome and Chromedriver via gitlab-ci.yml, Chromedriver is initiated by ‘- chromedriver --port=4444’. At this point, all steps stop as Chromedriver is running:

[image]

How do I ensure subsequent steps are initiated/completed in this scenario?

gitlab-ci.yml:

```
# Webapp automates testing
webapp:test:
  extends: .webapp:test
  stage: test
  allow_failure: true
  before_script:
    # Chrome and ChromeDriver dependencies
    - cd $APP_DIR
    - apt-get install -y wget unzip
    - wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
    - echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
    
    # Update the package list
    - apt-get update -y
    
    # Download and Install chrome
    - wget --no-verbose -O /tmp/chrome.deb https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && apt install -y /tmp/chrome.deb && rm /tmp/chrome.deb
    
    # Download and install Chromedriver
    - mkdir /chromedriver
    - wget -q --continue -P /chromedriver "https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/120.0.6099.109/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip"
    - unzip /chromedriver/chromedriver* -d /chromedriver 
    
    # Put Chromedriver into the PATH
    - chmod +x /chromedriver/chromedriver-linux64
    - export PATH="/chromedriver/chromedriver-linux64:$PATH"
    
    - |
      if [ "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" == "main" ]; then
        TEST_URL="https://rova.test.apps.goldcoast.qld.gov.au/"
      elif [ "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" == "test" ]; then
        TEST_URL="https://rova.test.apps.goldcoast.qld.gov.au/"
      elif [ "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" == "develop" ]; then
        TEST_URL="https://rova.dev.apps.goldcoast.qld.gov.au/"
      fi
  only:
    changes:
      - front-end/flutter-app/**/*
      - docker/base/**/*
      - back-end/serverless-functions/function-app/**/*
      - back-end/serverless-functions/function-app.tests/**/*
```

flutterapp.gitlab-ci.yml

```
## Webapp test 
.webapp:test: &webapp_test
  image: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/flutter:latest
  cache:
    paths:
      - .npm/
      - node_modules/
  script:
    - apt-get update && apt-get install -y jq
    - cd $APP_DIR
    - cd /chromedriver/chromedriver-linux64
    - chromedriver --version
    - chromedriver --port=4444
    - cd $APP_DIR
    - flutter drive --driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart --target=integration_test/start_page.dart -d web-server
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - $APP_DIR/test-results/
  when: always
  allow_failure: true
```

Please note, I am relatively new to GitLab CI, as you can probably tell. I am aware there may be further issues to resolve to get the one test running, once I can get past this issue, but am happy to receive any feedback at all on the way I have put this together.

Comment: I do not have much experience with chromedriver but it seems that it needs to be running in the background. Did you see the [documentation on e2e tests](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/end_to_end_testing_webdriverio/#configuring-gitlab-cicd) by GitLab?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following, which appears to start chromedriver as a background process:

```
- chromedriver --port=4444 &
```