# Should I run Flutter Integration Test in gitlab, using '-d chrome' or '-d web-server'

Tags: flutter, gitlab-ci

I am attempting to run an initial very basic Flutter Integration test in GitLab pipeline for Web only.  I have got to the point where chrome and chromedriver are installed, chromedriver is started and the test is started.

When the test is started with -d web-server

```
- flutter drive --driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart --target=integration_test/start_page.dart -d web-server
```

The following error is retuned:

> Launching integration_test/start_page.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
> Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...
> 37.1s [CHROME]:[3157:3157:0130/020726.569391:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(100)]
> Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See
> https://crbug.com/638180. Failed to launch browser after 3 tries.
> Command used to launch it: google-chrome
> --user-data-dir=/tmp/flutter_tools.ANJJPE/flutter_tools_chrome_device.WXZMXZ --remote-debugging-port=34719 --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-extensions --disable-popup-blocking --bwsi --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check --disable-default-apps --disable-translate http://localhost:36143 Failed to launch browser.

When the test is started with -d chrome

```
- flutter drive --driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart --target=integration_test/start_page.dart -d chrome
```

The following error is retuned:

> Launching integration_test/start_page.dart on Web Server in release
> mode... Compiling integration_test/start_page.dart for the Web...
> 54.1s integration_test/start_page.dart is being served at http://localhost:40579 The web-server device requires the Dart Debug
> Chrome extension for debugging. Consider using the Chrome or Edge
> devices for an improved development workflow.

I have tried to solve both ways unsuccessfully using various methods

- using '--release'
- using '- flutter config --enable-web'
- using - google-chrome --no-sandbox'

Are there any suggestions as to the correct method to use?